# systemd-cryptenroll with FIDO2

Tags: systemd, luks, fido-u2f

I've setup luks volume unlocking with FIDO2 along with recovery key using sd-cryptenroll:

```
systemd-cryptenroll --fido2-device=auto /dev/my-luks-device
```

Slots are configured as following:

```
SLOT TYPE    
   1 recovery
   3 fido2
```

Everything works fine, but in a weird way: on boot I get asked for the recovery key first, then I hit enter a couple of times, basically failing the recovery key, and only then I get prompted for fido2 with user presence.

I wonder if it's something to do with the slot order, although the man page doesn't mention anything about that. I've actually setup TPM2 unlocking before trying FIDO, and even if TPM was set to slot 2 I was never asked for recovery key first, so this might not be the issue here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My FIDO2 device is in the form of a Yubikey. It must be already connected to the computer before booting in order to be asked for the user presence.
Failing to to so and I get prompted for the passphrase.

However, if the enrollment was set to require the PIN, the Yubikey can be connected after the passphrase prompt shows up. Then entering the PIN instead of the passphrase unlocks the volume.

For reference, I did this with Fedora, and followed [this procedure](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2022/02/17/unlock-luks-volume-with-a-yubikey/) to setup the feature.